# Cakephp2 : Using multiple authentication manager

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I took back the maintenance of a cakephp app, however I have never been a cake developer  and I just encountered my first problem.

Currently users are logging in by using a simple form, it is something really simple and it looks like this:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('userModel'=> .....
```

Whenever I try to access a protected page, I am getting redirected to the page which implements this login form, this is totally fine and I don't have any problem with that.

However, I have different clients that requires different "authentication format" (if I may say), some wants an Ldap authentication, others an openId authentication, others a CAS authentication...

I managed to create a working authentication for every "system" by extending the `BaseAuthenticate` and implementing my logic to connect to the app.

Let's take the example with OpenId (which is a little explained in the cakephp book and that I base myself on : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html). I have created my `OpenIdAuthenticate` in `app/controller/component/auth`, implemented the method,...

As in the book, I have chosen the `openId` as the "main authentication" is my `appController` :

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'OpenId',
    'Form'
);
```

For the CAS I have the same with Cas instead of OpenId and whenever i try to access a protected page I am redirect to my cas server, where I log myself and I am logged in the cake application (so no problem).

I have also created another method in my user controller in case of the external authentication is broken (if we have any problem, it will probably be useful still to be able to log ourselves for maintenance).
To do so I created an adminLogin method (+ the ctp view file) where I "forced" the original Form authentication by doing as it was written before:

```
public function adminLogin() {
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('userModel'=> .....
    if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
       //rest of the logic
    }
}
```

Whenever I query the uri `/users/adminLogin`, I am using the classic authentication system and have access to  all the protected pages by bypassing the external authentication.

First question: Is it recommended to do something like that? The only goal is to have access to the content of the app as long as our database is up (in case of).

Now comes the part I still haven't found the solution. As I said, I have different clients with different needs and I don't want to have the classic version hosted for client X, the OpenId for the Y and the Ldap for the Z. I would like the same application everywhere and it will be up to the client to use whichever system he wants to use.

This means, I want to be able to change the authentication method dynamically. What i would like to do is to create a page (only available for the administrator obviously) where it will be able to choose between all the supported system and to configure the system.

For example, I choose Ldap, I will have to give the ip,port,reading suer and pwd, DN, filter,etc.... If I choose cas, the url,port,...(you understood).

And when I press the submit button, my authentication system has changed (except for the adminLogin page).

This is where I would like you to help me find a way to do so. I tried to create a global variable when I click on submit using

```
Configure::write('SystemUsed','LDAP');
```

And in my `appController` in the `beforeFilter()`, I tried to do :

```
if (Configure::read('SystemUsed') == 'LDAP') {
    $this->Auth->authenticate(...);
else if (Configure::read('SystemUsed') == 'OpenId') {
    $this->Auth->authenticate(...);
}
```

etc. But it is not working, the variable is becoming `null` after the submit and it doesn't look like a clean way to do it.

Can anyone help me, please?